# Using mutationobservers to detect changes in the results of a fetch request

Tags: javascript, vue.js, mutation-observers

I'm working on a narrow cast that displays an amount of tickets (an integer with the total added up to eachother) from a 3rd party API. I want to display a notification when this amount increases. I've read about mutationobservers, and that they are good for doing similar tasks like when something gets added or deleted.

The app has a Vue frontend, and a Laravel backend which does the requesting/authenticating. The index blade loads in a Vue component which contains the other components (and distributes the data from the API to child components).

I'm not quite sure wether mutationobservers are good for this specific job, though. Googling really didn't give me great alternatives.

In conclusion, I want to know if mutationobservers are the right tools for this task and what property would work. Better suited alternatives are also welcome.

Comment: In short, no, a mutation observer does not fit here. There are many variables at play here which we do not know. Does this 3rd party API use webhooks to inform you of a change? How do you know something has been added or removed from the 3rd party API?  Even if they support webhooks, it can still be tricky.  It appears most people using a Node backend like to use something called [Pusher](https://hackernoon.com/build-a-realtime-chart-with-vue-js-6527ac55c315) to notify clients of "realtime" changes. At the end of the day MO's only observe local changes to the dom not changes on a 3rd party api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using vue, you can use a watcher function to watch for changes in a particular variable (amount). Mutation Observers only watches for dom updates, it won't give you what you want